# Logistic regression model not finding significant correlation between parent column and quantile column

Tags: r, statistics

So i had original measurements as follows:

```
a = c(3.97, 7.27, 2.60, 6.15,   8.61,  -0.18,   2.93,   2.90,   3.64,   4.28, 120.38,   4.68,   4.98,   3.47,   1.04,   8.61,   7.85,  19.35,   7.01,  9.25,  15.53,   1.67,   7.66,   5.28,   6.02,   6.06,   4.03,   7.16,   2.63,   1.72,   4.70,   7.87,  -7.26,   5.55,   3.33,  68.00,  41.73,   1.85, 2.96,   4.92,   9.16,  31.95,  10.95,   3.81,   4.17,   6.79,   6.07,  10.40,  -2.77,   2.96,  -2.58,   8.39,   7.27,  70.89,   4.87,  19.55,   4.15, 5.47,   2.64,   9.62,   4.10,   6.75)
tmp = data.frame(a)
q = quantile(tmp$a, 0.8)
tmp$q80 = ifelse(tmp$a >= q, 1, 0)
```

from the original measurements in A i created an 80th percentile new column

Finally i then ran a logistic regression model on a larger dataset like so mod1 = glm(q80 ~ a + `B time min` + `C time min`,data = tmp, family ="binomial") for reproducibility lets leave out B and C and focus on the quantile column

```
mod1 = glm(q80 ~ a,data = tmp, family ="binomial")

summary(mod1)
```

Which returns p values of 0.994 for all three things. Now logically at least the quantile column should be significantly correlated using a sigmoidal curve as there is a clear cutoff at the 80th percent quantile where all values are 1.

Can someone explain where i messed up with a logistic regression model that does not find correlations between columns derived from each other?

Comment: `a` is a perfect predictor of `q80`, so the odds ratio is infinite.  you get warnings from `R` in this case that the algorithm hasn't converged.  The reported estimate, se and p-value are meaningless.

Comment: I had disabled warnings, i see now that was a dire mistake. Thanks for the help

Comment: modelling warnings in particular are essential.